# Accessing servlets hosted on another computer

Tags: java, apache, servlets

I have a servlet hosted on an Apache tomcat server.. It can be accessed the usual way on the same computer using localhost IPaddress. I would like to know how to access it using another computer while this computer is running.

Answer (score 2):

if host is reachable

```
http://ipOfHostMachine:portOnWhichServerRuns/appcontext/yourServlet
```

**For Example**

```
http://192.1.200.1:8080/myApp/MyServlet
```